# Why aren't my creds being passed into my nginx.conf?

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

My original nginx.conf:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
    include credentials.conf; 
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Authorization $credentials;
            proxy_pass [website_of_choice];
        }
    }
}
```

My credentials.conf:

```
set $credentials 'Basic [long_encoded_login_details]';
```

But this wont work when nginx starts.

Comment: This should work, what is the error that you get?

Comment: When I have the credentials hard coded = my iframe on my webapp displays it's contents. When I use the method above: I receive "localhost could not connect" within the iframe.

Comment: Enable debug-mode (find the error_log directive and use the loglevel `debug`) to see the actual requst send to the Backend. This configuration will work. Its workin in my lab.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.conf` as a file ending will not work in some cases. This should give you an error trying to reload nginx `sudo nginx -s reload` or `nginx -t` on configtest. This depends on your nginx.conf. Check if there is any `include` directive including anything `*.conf` from a given directory.

use this

credentials.include

```
set $credentials 'Basic [long_encoded_login_details]';
```

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
    server {
    include credentials.include; 
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Authorization $credentials;
            proxy_pass [website_of_choice];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both methods now. Both (in the docker logs) say 2021/04/05 12:49:04 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/credentials.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4. I have tried redoing but including the full/relative filepath but it still looks in /etc/nginx rather than the filepath I have stated.

Comment: okay... where do you have the credentials.include file? in /etc/nginx/? If so the include will be `include credentials.conf`. The include is always relative to `/etc7nginx/`. Please check this.